# Hide devices selection from customizer?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Is it possible to hide the device selection from the Customizer. And if it is possible to hide it for a specific User Role, that would be fantastic.

I mean this one:
[image: Picture of device selection in Customizer]

Comment: What's the context for this?

Comment: only admin should have access to the customizer, so not sure what is the point about denying other roles

Comment: It is a multisite. And i want then gone to simplify things as they are not necessary for my site. Would it be possible?

Comment: I think you could try to conditionally enqueue a CSS for the admin area with display:none as a simple and quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a [`customize_previewable_devices` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_previewable_devices/) which is used to manage which devices are displayed here. For example, to conditionally remove the Tablet device, do:

```
add_filter( 'customize_previewable_devices', function( $devices ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'do_something' ) ) {
        unset( $devices['tablet'] );
    }
    return $devices;
} );
```